# zero denominator in ROC and Precision-Recall?

Tags: information-retrieval, roc, precision-recall

This question is about the ROC curve, but it can be generalized to the Precision-Recall curve.

As you may know, the row curve is drawn using the False Positives Rate (`FPR`) and the True Positives Rate (`TPR`), where:

```
TPR = tp / (tp + fn ) // tp= true positives, fn = false negatives
FPR = fp / (fp + tn ) // fp = false positives, tn = true negatives
```

But what if one of the denominators is 0? The optimal value of `TPR` is 1, while `FPR` is 0 (in fact the optimal point in the ROC space is `(0,1)`).

This is particularly important if we use the ROC curve to compute the optimal threshold in a classification system.

For example, in my case, my system for a particular configuration never returns `fp` or `tn`, so `FPR` has always 0 as denominator

**Update for clarification:**

I'm using T-F/P-N and the ROC curve to decide a threshold value for my classifier. In particular, I compute these values for a given cut-off on the top-`k` most similar elements in the dataset w.r.t. the given query.  So it happens that if we consider only the top-`1` elements, the T-F/P-N are calculated only on very similar objects, so it's very realistic that the classifier doesn't return negatives. As result, the threshold is very strict, but the classifier is very precise. Something like "I don't know what to answer many times, but when I do, I give the correct answer almost 100% of the times".

Of course, if we increase `k` negatives appears and the threshold increase. As result, the classifier answer more often, but the probability of wrong results is higher.

So I think I will keep `k` as a tuning parameter, depending on the considered application: if we want a very precise classifier, we will set a small `k`, otherwise if we contemplate false positives we can choose a larger `k`.

**My application:**

My app is a similarity cache for images: when received a query, the system check if there is a "enough similar" cached image. If so, returns the same result, otherwise query the back end system. "similar enough" is the threshold. To decide a good threshold, we select a subset of dataset images, the so called "queries" in this question. To decide the threshold, as I explained above, as first approach I select the top-`1` elements, i.e. the most similar image w.r.t. the query (one of the setup image) in the whole dataset. This is done for each query. From there, I compute the threshold using the ROC curve as explained above. So, if we use `n` queries, we obtain `n` predictions.

If we use this approach, the resulting threshold is very strict, because since we consider the top-`1` element, the average distance is very small (and very precise) and so we obtain a strict threshold.

If we use the top-`k` approach (say `k=10`), we select the top `k` most similar images and we do the same approach as above. The threshold becomes larger, we have more cache hits, but also the probability of false-positives is higher. In this case we obtain `k*n` predictions. If we set `k` as the whole dataset with size `m`, we obtaiin `k*m` predictions.

I hope this clarifies my previous **UPDATE**

Comment: No FP and no TN suggests you have no negative examples, only positives. I'm not quite sure what is left to optimize in this case... just predict everything as positive with a dummy classifier?

Comment: So basically you actually have a sort of ternary classifier that can say "positive", "negative" or "no call", is that correct?

Comment: Actually I don't get "I compute these values for a given cut-off on the top-k most similar elements in the dataset". The cut-off is on the decision threshold, not on the data points.

Comment: @Calimo thanks again for your comment. I updated again my question exaplining my application and the top-k concept, I hope that clarifies everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just check whether the numerator equals 0 before computing your ratio. For example

```
if (fp == 0):
  return 0.0
return fp/(fp + tn)
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, that makes totally sense. One simple question: why `return 0`? Is that because `fp=0` is an ideal case and so we return the optimal value? If that's the case, we should `return 0` also when when we compute `TPR`, since `tp=0` is the worst case (and we want to maximize `TPR`).  Am I correct?

Comment: With these extremes, your `roc curve` simply becomes a vertical `(fp = 0)` or horizontal `(tp = 0)` line. The reason to return `0.0` is simply because `0/x equals 0 for all values of x not equal to 0' If x equals 0 this would imply that you have no false positives and no true negatives. Thus all of your negatives are false negatives and all of your positives are true positives. Therefore, your FPR equals 0 for all possible values of TPR. This translates to you having chosen a model which perfect precision and variable recall which depends on the number of false negatives you have.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, it solved all my doubts!

Comment: @BrianVanover "all of your negatives are false negatives and all of your positives are true positives" is misleading at best, and should read "all of your negative predictions are false negatives and all of your positive predictions are true positives".

Comment: Therefore you have no "gold" negative observation, and the FPR is simply undefined, as it is the proportion of negative events wrongly classified as positive. You simply have no data to calculate it, and using 0 is unjustifiably optimistic. If replacing with a number is really required then at least use 1 as a more conservative estimate.

Comment: @BrianVanover  I updated my question giving more details and some considerations. I would really appreciate if you can check it out

Comment: @Calimo, I agree with your statement. This is not an ideal situation to be in. It basically implies that the model has not been evaluated against correctly classifying negative data. The OP could have a model that classifies all observations as positive and get a similar result. However, I would claim that the ROC curve is generated against a single hold out evaluation set. I could be misusing the term here, but it seems similar to the `no free lunch` phenomena. While the performance may look ok here if evaluated using `FPR`, it only applies to the given hold-out test set.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have no FP and no TN indicates you have no negative examples, only positives. Therefore **you can not calculate** what proportion of them would be wrongly classified as positive by your classifier. It could be 0 or 100%, there is no way to know.

You need to collect some "gold" negatives and see how your classifier performs on them. Failing to do so, you risk to select a "dummy" classifier that assign the positive class to all observations, with 100% accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question giving more details and some considerations. I would really appreciate if you can check it out.